# Забрать значения из динамически создаваемых input.

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Есть форма добавления электронных адресов для пользовательской рассылки email сообщений. Форма простая - один input и две кнопки: "Еще email" и "Выбрать", при желании пользователь может добавить неограниченное количество адресов. Теперь сам вопрос: Как забрать из всех input введенные значения и записать например в массив PHP.

```js
function addField () {
 var telnum = parseInt($('#add_field_area').find('div.add:last').attr('id').slice(3))+1;
 $('div#add_field_area').append('<div id="add'+telnum+'" class="add"><label> Пользователь ' +telnum+'</label><input type="text" width="120" name="val[]" id="val"  value=""/><div class="deletebutton" onclick="deleteField('+telnum+');"></div></div>');
        }

        function deleteField (id) {
            $('div#add'+id).remove();
        }
```

```html
<form class="test" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<div class="box_uses">

        <div id="add_field_area">
            <?
            $array = '';
            $values = explode("|",$array);
            $n = 0;
            foreach ($values as $value) {
                $n++;
                if ($n == 1) {
                    ?><div id="add1" class="add">
                    <label>Пользователь <?=$n?></label>
                    <input type="text" width="120" name="val<?=$n?>" id="val<?=$n?>"  value="<?=$value?>"/>
                    </div>
                    <?
                } else {
                    ?>
                    <div id="add<?=$n?>" class="add">
                        <label>Пользователь <?=$n?></label>
                        <input type="text" width="120" name="val<?=$n?>" id="val<?=$n?>"  value="<?=$value?>"/>
                        <div class="deletebutton" onclick="deleteField(<?=$n?>);"></div>

                    </div>

                    <?

                }
            }

            ?>

        </div>
        <div onclick="addField();" class="button">Добавить еще email</div>
        <input type="button" class="button" style="margin: 10px 0 10px 5px;" value="Выбрать" title="Выбрать" onclick="addUsesOutSystem()">
    </div>
 </form>
```

Спасибо заранее за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const button = document.getElementById('butt');
const mails = [];
button.addEventListener('click', function(){
let input = document.getElementsByClassName('input-mail');
for (elem of input){
  mails.push(elem.value);
}
  console.log(mails);
})
```

```html
<div id="add_field_area">
<input class='input-mail' type="text">
<input class='input-mail' type="text">
<input class='input-mail' type="text">
</div>
<button id='butt'>Получить mail</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо за наглядный пример!!!